# How to separate text from .txt in an Array. JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, text, filereader

I'm coding in Java and I need to separate text that I get from a .txt into different parts of an Array. The text is composed by different "texts" like a collection of documents.
The line before each text is something like: "*TEXT" and some numbers, but I think, that with the only word "*TEXT" it can be divided each text.
An example of how is the .txt:

```
*TEXT 017 01/04/63 PAGE 020
THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S ........
*TEXT 020 01/04/63 PAGE 021
THE ROAD TO JAIL IS PAVED WITH NONOBJECTIVE ART SINCE THE KREMLIN'S SHARPEST BARBS THESE DAYS ARE AIMED AT MODERN ART AND WESTERN ESPIONAGE...
*TEXT 025 01/04/63 PAGE 024
RED CHINA FIXING FRONTIERS RED CHINA PRODUCED A SECOND SURPRISE LAST WEEK...
```

So I need the text 017 in a position of the array and in the next position will be the text 020.
How can I do this?

This is the code of how I get the text from the .txt using FileReader:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Reader{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        File inFile;
        FileReader fr;
        BufferedReader bufReader;
        JFileChooser chooser;

        int reply;
        String doc = "";

        String line;
        try{
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            reply = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            doc = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") +
                chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            inFile = new File(doc);
            fr = new FileReader(inFile);
            bufReader = new BufferedReader (fr);

            do{
                line = bufReader.readLine();
                if(line ==null )
                    return;
                else{
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } while(line!=null);

            bufReader.close();

        }//end try
        catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());   }
    }//main
}//end class reader
```

Comment: Wait you want the actual text? or the number?  Your question makes it seems like you just want the 017 or 020 in the array.  If you want the whole text then yeah just do a split.

Comment: I want the whole text, sorry not very good at english? :/

Answer (score 2):

You could just read the entire file into a String and then use String.split(String regex)

Comment: I have "line" that is a String in the beggining, can i uses that with the String.split? @Kristian Kostadinov

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to read the file and then you can just split it, like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (String s:FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/home/leoks/file.txt")).split("\n")){
        if (s.startsWith("*TEXT")) {
            System.out.println(s.split(" ")[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

or you can write a parser using something like this

```
http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=*TEXT%20017&-14&-1
```

Comment: If i use your first code, inside the "new File()" i need to put my String of the whole text (Line)?
And then its going to print all the "texts" separate?

Comment: scroll my answer to the right, you'll see I am splitting by \n :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, disregard my answer.  I typed it so i'm leaving it but I thought he just wanted the text number that was after the "*TEXT" identifiers.

Try regular expressions and captures.

```
String text = "this will be your document text"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*TEXT ([0-9]{3}))+.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
int numCounts = m.groupCount();
String texts[] = new String[numCounts];
for (int i = 1; i <= numCounts; i++) {
   // group(0) is whole match you want each group a 1
   texts[i-1] = m.group(i);  
}
// now they should be in your texts
```

OR you can do this:

```
String text = "this will be your document text"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("TEXT ([0-9]{3})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
  list.add(m.group(1));
}
String texts[] = list.toArray();
// now they should be in your texts
```

Comment: No, i dont want the number after the "TEXT". I want to try filling the array, and in each position have a String of each text (*TEXT).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                           new FileInputStream("yourTextFile")));
StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
String newLine ="";
while(true){
   String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
   if(line == null)
      break;
   br.append(line);
}
newLine = br.toString();
String arr[] = newLine.split("\\*TEXT");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```